# Mercurial & Keyword ext.: updating keywords when tagging a revision

Tags: mercurial, keyword, mercurial-extension

I'm using Mercurial with the keyword extention, and I'm very pleased with it. Expect one thing, expanding the version tag which is:

```
Version = {latesttag|nonempty}
```

All the keywords are expanded as expected on every check in. But when I'm tagging a revision, nothing happens at this moment. I expect/want to expand the tags in all files. Right now the version tag gets updated/expanded on the next commit of a file. I guess, I have to do this with a hook, but i stuck with this.
Any suggestions?
Thank you very much

Roland

Answer (score 0):

- Your filter do nothing, because for repository without tags `{latesttag} returns "null" text-string
- Keywords in files have "this file" scope, not global, i.e reflect only state at the time of *last change of file*, and, for tagging (which commit only `.hgtags`) not changing `$Version$` is expected

> All the keywords are expanded as expected on every check in

Only for files *in this changeset*, not included files aren't touched. See at final content of two (originally identical) files in repo

> Current version of file: $Version$ and $Revision$

each of which was committed some times separately

```
>hg log file.txt -l 1
changeset:   5:3ceaea734895

>hg log file2.txt -l 1
changeset:   3:09939c9b8243
```

file.txt

```
Current version of file: $Version: v 0.1 $ and $Revision: 3ceaea734895 $
```

file2.txt

```
Current version of file: $Version: v 0.1 $ and $Revision: 09939c9b8243 $
```

If you want to change keywords in all files for every commit, you can|have to include files in questions in every commit (it can be alias, which uses `commit -I`)

Comment: THX, i'll see how to do this with TortoiseHG

Comment: @RolandSchmitz - no ways to write alias in GUI, you have to edit .hgrc by hand

Comment: Right, i did not want to write it via GUI, i want to use it via GUI :-)
So adding something like:
    `[alias]
    add_all = commit -I **.*`

But how do i use this lateron via TortoiseHG?

Comment: I tried following alias `tag = hg commit -I "*.pl" -I "*.pm" && hg tag --rev 0  "$@"`
But if i try to tag something, i get `hg tag: option --rev not recognized
alias 'tag' resolves to unknown command 'hg'
[command returned code 255 Mon Nov 16 14:18:47 2015]`

Comment: @RolandSchmitz: 1. tag -r 0??? `-r .` definitely (or without -r for "current changeset" at all) 2. aliases are aliases for *hg commands*, `hg` assumed and not used (see internal alias in https://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#alias) 3. `&&` isn't internal feature for Mercurial, I'm afraid after fixing pp. 1-2 you'll have to rewrite alias to SHELL-alias 4. `-m ...` is NEEDED in `hg commit` commit for non-interactive commit

Comment: @RolandSchmitz "how do i use this lateron via TortoiseHG?" - you can (newer tried) add custom tool to own button into (any) toolbar

Comment: Ok, lot's of information, i will check what to to next weekend, Thank you very much